Caucasian man wakes up in darkened room after a night out and has to drink his own urine
Man (Caucasian) wakes up in a darkened room after a night out. Has no idea how he got there. No doors or windows and the walls appear to be seamless.
Don't know how much time passes but he runs out of water and winds up drinking his own urine using a shoe as a receptacle (I forgot if he had anything to eat or not).
He can hear humming behind the walls but has no clue as to what it is.
One day, he notices tapping on part of the wall. He goes to it and taps back. So he knows someone is on the other side.
They tap over a period of time (days?) and eventually he wakes one morning to find that a panel to the next room has opened. He enters and finds a woman (Black) who speaks only in her native tongue (some African language, I think).
She doesn't trust him plus they can't really communicate. She eventually comes around--he even shows her the use-shoe-to-catch-your-urine trick so they have a water supply of sorts.
Even though there is a language barrier, once trust has been established, the inevitable (?) happens and they have sex.
One time they were on the same side of the wall, that panel slides down and now they are trapped in the same room.
Time passes and one day, it's as if the room lands and a panel opens. They step outside to look at the sky and we see a multitude of planets in the sky. We also see other rooms have landed and other couples have come out of them. Apparently, they were all on a space journey that dropped them on another planet.
Anyone remember what this is called?

When did you watched it? Release year or decade?

Iron Doors (2010)

A young man must escape from a mysterious locked vault before he dies
  of dehydration.

*He talks to himself and repeatedly uses every curse word known to man before he drinks his own urine out of his shoe and eats some maggots and then talks to himself about drinking urine and eating maggots.
*He bangs a hole in the wall and finds an African woman in another room with another big iron door.



